# how to pair two rows based on the event type and time stamp in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario, where I need to pair two rows based on its property number(VAL1) and the Event type and event date. Please see the below snapshots of data that is coming from the source and the second snapshot is what expected. Can you please help me , if there is a way in oracle to achieve this?

Thank you in Advance!

Source:

[image: This is the data from the Source]

Target: (Expected)

[image: This is the expected Output]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions, then aggregation:

```
select 
    listagg(id)   within group(order by eventdate) ids,
    listagg(type) within group(order by eventdate) types,
    min(eventdate) eventstart,
    max(eventdate) eventend,
    val1,
    val2
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by val1, val2 order by eventdate) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by floor((rn - 1)/2), val1, val2
```

This generates pairs of rows that have the same `(val1, val2)`, ordered by ascending `eventdate`: every two rows are grouped together.

Comment: But, we can get multiple rows that can have same Val1 and Val2. not just 2. If you see, in my example, Rows 1,2 and 5,6 have the same values for Val1 and Val2.

Comment: @Edu: yes, I understand that. The query properly handles that, using the aggregation condition on `floor((rn-1)/2)`. Give it a try against your data and find out by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But, I have been trying to get this worked out. I am using Advanced Query tool and the function LISTAGG is not being supported here. Is there any other way to replace LISTAGG in this? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a little bit of aggregation. Sample data from line #1 to 7; query that actually does the job begins at line #8.

```
SQL> with test (id, type, event_date, val1, val2) as
  2    (select '1-1001', 'type-1', date '2020-10-14', 1234, 'abc' from dual union all
  3     select '1-1002', 'type-2', date '2020-10-15', 1234, 'abc' from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select '1-1025', 'type-1', date '2020-09-01', 1123, 'abc' from dual union all
  6     select '1-1026', 'type-2', date '2020-09-02', 1123, 'abc' from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    listagg(id, ', ') within group (order by event_date) ids,
 10    listagg(type, ', ') within group (order by event_date) types,
 11    min(event_date) event_start_dt,
 12    max(event_date) event_end_dt,
 13    val1,
 14    val2
 15  from test
 16  group by val1, val2
 17  order by 1;

IDS             TYPES           EVENT_STAR EVENT_END_       VAL1 VAL
--------------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
1-1001, 1-1002  type-1, type-2  2020-10-14 2020-10-15       1234 abc
1-1025, 1-1026  type-1, type-2  2020-09-01 2020-09-02       1123 abc

SQL>
```